# How to attach to all Jquery.UI.dialog open events to dynamically resize dialog on open?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm working with a large existing codebase with tons of legacy code I can't change. My task is to upgrade to the 1.8 version of the UI library. I am having issues with the positioning of a jquery.ui.dialog() element.

The entire site is loaded via javascript ( which I guess is the rage right now ). Tons of HTML gets loaded dynamical which causes positioning issues with the dialog box.  Previously the site used custom css position:relative to make sure all of the dialogs were positioned ok.

The dialog's are setup like this:

```
    $('#deletingDialog').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, position: 'center' });
```

With UI 1.8 there has been a change in the way dialog() works which breaks this behavior:
http://jqueryui.com/docs/Upgrade_Guide/1.8.6

> Don't change DOM position on open
>
> Dialogs no longer get moved around in
>   the DOM when they are opened. The only
>   time the dialog is moved now is during
>   initialization when it is appended to
>   the body. This fixes a slew of
>   problems, such as form elements being
>   reset, iframes reloading, etc.

All of the dialog() setup code is bound to html elements very early and is in several different places.  In a perfect world I'd be able to get in there and change all the dialog calls to be late bound and only setup right before the dialog is supposed to open. This would most likely fix the issue.  Unfortunately changing all this code is really prohibitive and defiantly not an option.

What I'm thinking is hooking into the dialog open event http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open and resetting the position right before the modal window actually opens.

So either I can find all the elements with dialogs and then bind via `$( ".selector" ).bind( "dialogopen"` etc etc or hook into the event globally ( preferred ).  Either I need a way to say "give me all the elements with a dialog attached" or "always do this code when the open event happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Either I need a way to say "give me
>   all the elements with a dialog
>   attached" or "always do this code when
>   the open event happens.

I think your first idea of using a selector to select all elements that have a dialog widget associated with them.  This should be relatively easy--a `class` `ui-dialog-content` is applied to each element that the dialog widget is applied to (a wrapper `div` is inserted around the content).  So your code would be:

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").bind("dialogopen", function() {
    // Reposition dialog, 'this' refers to the element the even occurred on.
    $(this).dialog("option", "position", "top");  
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is what I did before you answered.  Useful for the next guy though.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jason: Should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Aa5nK/99/. That fiddle uses the latest jQueryUI and logs out the current position.

Comment: instead of bind, I went with on: `$(document).on("dialogopen", ".ui-dialog", function (event, ui) {`

Comment: You want to use live, not bind if you want to guarantee it to work with dialogs created after the DOM has been loaded.  (The comment above, which illustrates binding it to document object,  essentially  accomplished the same thing as live, but is not using the jquery framework:
$(".ui-dialog").live("dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
 console.log('Open sesame '); 
});

Comment: Actually @Jeffrey, as of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers replacing `$.live` and `$.bind`.

Answer (score 3):

That my solution

```
// repositioning of all rising dialogs
$(document).on("dialogopen", ".ui-dialog", function (event, ui) {
    var t = $(event.currentTarget), w = $(window);

    $(this).css({
        top: (w.height() / 2) - (t.height() / 2),
        left: (w.width() / 2) - (t.width() / 2)
    })
});
```

Comment: Best answer for my solution.